# In Meteor, how to short-circuit-assign a helper variable with user object?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm running the latest Meteor (v1.1.0.3) on OS X 10.6.8 in Firefox 39.0.
I'm using `accounts-ui` and `accounts-google` for login management.  I have a hand-rolled profile form with (among other things) a 'name' field.  The initial value of this field should be either the name that is already set in their profile or the one that Google supplies.

I've defined the following template helper:

```
Template.profile_edit.helpers({
    my_name: (function () {var u=Meteor.user(); return u.profile.name || u.services.google.name;}())
});
```

I use the value in my template as `{{ my_name }}`.  When I start meteor everything compiles just fine, but when I load the profile page I get the following Javascript error:

```
TypeError: u is undefined
...me: (function () {var u=Meteor.user(); return u.profile.name || u.services.googl...
```

Not immediately relevant, but just for completeness:

- After the page loads, the 'name' field in the form is blank.
- I *am* logged in.
- When I pull up Meteor's mongo instance in my terminal I can see my user record; the name in the profile is NOT set, the name in the services.google.name IS set.

Why is this error happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: Do you get the error but _still_ see the value appear in your template, maybe a bit later?

Comment: Did you removed autopublish?

Comment: (Pardon the long ping time; I've been traveling.)

@Kyll: No, I get the error and the value remains blank.

Comment: @LaxmikantDange: No, I haven't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Problem**

This is a common issue that people have when first starting out with Meteor. The problem is that when this helper is executed during page load, depending on the response time for the publication from the server, the data for the currently logged in user may not be available yet. This makes it seem intermittent because at times the data is published in time, and others it's not.

**Possible Solutions**

One possible solution is to install `meteorhacks:fast-render`. This will publish the logged in user (due to the null publication) with the initial html for the page and guarantee that the user is available when this helper is run. Data other than the currently logged in user will need to be properly set up as subscriptions on the router for fast render to take effect.

The other solution, and one that will work without installation of a new package is to guard against undefined. This will effectively let the helper return undefined when there is no data, but once the data is available the helper will reactively rerun and the proper data will be returned.

```
Template.profile_edit.helpers({
    my_name: function () {
        var u=Meteor.user();
        if(u){
          return u.profile.name || u.services.google.name;
        }
    }
});
```

**Aside**

In your helper I notice that you are using syntax like `my_name:(function(){}())`. While this will give you what seems like a desired outcome, the problem is that you are immediately invoking this function and assigning its value to the `my_name` helper instead of assigning it a function that can be called multiple times when the value changes. This breaks reactivity and so the second solution would not work due to it's reliance on it.

```
Template.profile_edit.helpers({
    my_name: (function () {
        /*
           This is immediately invoked and basically
           like using my_name: "bob"
        */ 
    }())
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  This worked perfectly although, oddly, not for the reason indicated.  :>   I had actually had a conditional in my template to validate that the user was loaded, and it worked properly -- when I went to the page it said 'please login before editing profile', and then a moment later it would update to the form.  That was part of the confusion -- I knew I had a user object, so why was it failing?

Comment: Grrr.  I hit 'return' instead of 'shift-return' and accidentally posted.  

The rest of that was supposed to be:

Your post fixed it: I used `Meteor.user` instead of `Meteor.user()`.  I'm especially glad for the answer, as I didn't know about the timing issue: I hadn't thought about the user object not being avilable in time, I just put the conditional there to guard against people who hadn't created an account. Thanks again!